# Wordpress Sort by date on meta field or last modifed date

Tags: wordpress

I like to sort by date.
While meta key pdate is exist, I like to use it as date.
If meta key pdate is not exist, I like to use last modifed date.

This code shows sorted posts by pdate.  It works.  Now Im wondering how I can add last modifed date into this code.

```
<?php
$paged = (int) get_query_var('paged');
$args = array(
    'paged'       => $paged,
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'pdate',
    'type'        => 'DATE',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
);
?>
```

Now, I think I could set date data in $date.

Somebody, please teach me how I can let him sort by $date... or how I can let him consider $date as date to him.

```
<?php
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdate',true)):
$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdate', true );
else
$date = get_the_modified_date(); 

        $paged = (int) get_query_var('paged');
        $args = array(

            'paged' => $paged,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'type'  => 'DATE',

);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call $date in an arg key which won't work. If you're trying to order by date, why not just call `'orderby' => 'date'`

Otherwise, by the looks of what you're trying to do the structure of it is wrong. If you're trying to specify a specific date you need to call the following within `$args = array()`

```
'date_query' => array(
  array (
    'year' => 2020,
    'month' => 03,
    'day' => 03,
 )
);
```

Too accomplish this fully, you might need to destructure the date returned within $date and apply the results to the `'date_query'` array.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  I changed my code to make my question simple.  I will search about what is date_query.  Thank you   @Oliver.

Comment: No problem, only problem that may be found is that it might only return those of the exact date. Could be worthwhile conditionally rendering two separate `$arg = array()` in an if/else to get two different results :)

Comment: Thanks again.  Now I found 'date_query' accepts parameters like year, month, after, before...and so on.  I can not find out how I can put last modifed date in date_query.

Comment: My best advice would be to work on a function that breaks apart the `get_the_modified_date()` into an array so you have the 3 values separately as `$date[0], $date[1], $date[2]`. Although you'll probably need to run a `preg_replace` for letters on the first index of the array if it returns with st, rd, nd at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help again.  I will try to separate $date.  @Oliver

Comment: Not a problem, hope you manage to get it working how you want it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This method**

```
<?php    
$text_content = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => '10' ,
    'post_type'      => 'text_content ',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'       => 'text_content_date ',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
) );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  I think it works for date on meta key.  Now Im wodering how I can add other conditon like modefied date with meta date. @Bloody

Comment: use this-     'meta_query'        => array(
        'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
        'type'              => 'DATETIME',  // You can also try changing it to TIME or DATE if it doesn't work
        'meta_value'        => date( "F d, Y g:i a" ),
        'meta_compare'      => '>',
    ),

Comment: Thanks again.@Bloody  It works to sort by date or time of meta field.  That is ok.  Now Im wondering how I combine it with date I can get from 'get_the_modified_date()'.